# Order in many to many relation in Django model

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I am writing a small website to store the papers I have written. The relation papers<-> author is important, but the order of the name of the authors (which one is First Author, which one is second order, and so on) is also important.

I am just learning Django so I don't know much. In any case so far I have done:

```
from django.db import models

class author(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    URLField = models.URLField(verify_exists=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Name

class topic(models.Model):        
    TopicName = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.TopicName

class publication(models.Model):
    Title           = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Authors         = models.ManyToManyField(author, null=True, blank=True)
    Content         = models.TextField()
    Notes           = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Abstract        = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date        = models.DateField('date published')
    TimeInsertion   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    URLField        = models.URLField(verify_exists=True,null=True, blank=True)
    Topic           = models.ManyToManyField(topic, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Title
```

This work fine in the sense that I now can define who the authors are. But I cannot order them. How should I do that?

Of course I could add a series of relations: first author, second author,...
but it would be ugly, and would not be flexible. Any better idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could add a ['through' model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) to that ManyToMany relationship and in that model, store a value that shows the order the Author should come in this particular association with a Publication.

(Bonus tip - it might help you down the line - in terms of clarity - to use initial capital letters for class/model names and keep lowercase for attributes and instances/objects - that way if you're sharing code with others, it'll be easier as it's a common pattern)

Comment: Regarding the uppercase and the lowercase: ok, I stand corrected.

Comment: Regarding the "through" model. I will try it. I am not so convinced yet, as it still feels rather un-elegant. I am trying to record a list of elements, and the "best" way is to write next to each element the position where it occurs? Python must have spoiled me if this really feels clumsy. It can be broken in all possible ways: positions can be repeated, positions can be jumped; if we forget a name we need to change the position for all the others. Thanks anyway. Pietro

Comment: The bit on positions can be remedied by using "importance" instead of "priority" That is the most prioritized author usually has a rank of 1. The most important author though would have the highest importance value. With other words, you could sort on highest value first (desc instead of asc) and in the output just enumerate whatever author relations are found. Leave additional space between the numbers to solve the issue with forgotten authors. I know this post was kinda old, but wanted to add this for completeness anyway.

Comment: On a counter-note, the described use case is literally the one I'm currently trying to get rid of, as the order of authors is incredibly important when it comes to publications, and listing the "most important author" first means no other authors can ever rise to prominence =)